# How to Stop C/C++ WINAPI Window Showing on all Desktops?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a C/C++ windows app which calls CreateWindow as follows:

`HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(pszClassName, title_.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SIZEBOX, 50, 50, 400, 100, NULL, NULL, hInst, this);`

Nothing particularly complex about it, however, it is appearing on every desktop on my computer when I switch from one desktop to another with CTRL-WIN < or >.

How do you make window you create in an app remain only on the desktop that you created it on?

I am compiling this app in 64bit and running it on Windows 10.

Comment: `CTRL-WIN-ARROW` toggles between *virtual desktops* within the same *physical desktop* of a *user session*. A window is tied to the *session desktop* it is created in, and is accessible to all *virtual desktops* within that *session*. You can't force a window to exist only in a specific *virtual desktop* (well, unless you monitor the desktops and manually call `IVirtualDesktopManager::MoveWindowToDesktop()`). The user can freely choose which window(s) to work with inside each *virtual desktop*, move windows between *virtual desktops*, etc. Your app should not force its own control over that.

Comment: @Remy I am not following you.My problem is that the window I create with the code above appears on all my virtual desktops, not just the one it is created in.

I want to have this window I create appear only where it is created.

I found if I make the window a child of another then it will only appear in that desktop, however this is not useful for my application.

Looking for the correct code to ensure a window only appears on the desktop it is created on.

Comment: "*the window I create with the code above appears on all my virtual desktops,*" - check if you have enabled the "Show on all virtual desktops" option for that particular window. "*I want to have this window I create appear only where it is created*" - that is the actual behavior when "Show on all virtual desktops" is not enabled. See [this explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180501-00/?p=98645). "*Looking for the correct code to ensure a window only appears on the desktop it is created on.*" - there is no code to force that. The window appears where the user specifies.

Comment: "Show on all virtual desktops" is not selected. I am also not touching anything to do with virtual desktops on my code.

The only thing I can think might be happening is that when I call the CreateWindow function I am passing NULL as the parent. In Windows 10 with a virtual desktop environment does doing this mean something different than other Win OS versions? Do I need to pass it the handle of the virtual desktop that I want it to appear on?

Comment: did you try removing WS_POPUP? I have same problem with WS_EX_NOACTIVATE which i think is either a win bug or poor choice! WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW i can understand. all out of things to try :(

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no difference. I am actually seeing this problem on some third party applications as well. Seems there is something buggy in the way some windows are handled in the virtual desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

Global:

```
 WNDCLASSEX wc;
```

Window procedure:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if(wParam == VK_F11)
    {
          wc.style = HWND_DESKTOP;//The window is child 
//of desktop
     }

     break;
```

WinMain:

```
LPCSTR windowName = "Answer on StackOwerflow";
MSG messages;

wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "The classname";
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);


hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    wc.lpszClassName,
    windowName,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

ShowWindow(hWnd);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);


while(GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

return 0;
```